# Python Selenium Click Next Button

Tags: python

I need to click the "next" button on the following page:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox/ref=gbps_ftr_s-4_bedf_wht_29726380?gb_f_deals1=dealStates:AVAILABLE%252CWAITLIST%252CWAITLISTFULL%252CEXPIRED%252CSOLDOUT%252CUPCOMING,includedAccessTypes:,sortOrder:BY_SCORE,enforcedCategories:2972638011&pf_rd_p=afc45143-5c9c-4b30-8d5c-d838e760bedf&pf_rd_s=slot-4&pf_rd_t=701&pf_rd_i=gb_main&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=60XTK6YDM9WEAFXB6519&ie=UTF8

I have the following code that will not find xpath element for the "next button":

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class='a-pagination']/li[@class='a-last']/a").click() # Click on next button
```

I have also tried this variation:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='pagination-next-6885645543374035']/ul/li[@class='a-last']/a")
```

I also tried directly copying the xpath from the inspector. Neither of these three options work.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried browser.find_element_by_id('args')? Or are you specifically wanting to use xpath?

Comment: I'm up for anything that works. Do you have an example based on the html structure? Thanks!

Comment: I will show you how to do it today when I get off work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Amazon attaches a numerical ending onto the ID that is different each time the page loads. Finally found a way to select it using xpath:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-declarative']/div[2]/ul/li[@class='a-last']/a")
```